# $1st$ Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it possible that a first order differential equation has no solution?

For example, a first order differential equation where the variables can't be separated, the terms are not homogeneous on each other, and $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are not exact.

Is it possible to have that kind of first order differential equation? If it is possible, what are the other techniques to solve such differential equation?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: You need to violate the conditions of the existence theorems everywhere. If these conditions hold in some open set, then there is a local solution, however small its domain.

Comment: The fact that you can't solve an equation doesn't mean that it has no solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy%27s_example#The_example) is about a first-order **partial** differential equation in **two** variables, where one of the derivatives is with respect to the **complex conjugate of** one of the two variables. The point is that this is an example of a differential equation with no solutions.